# Encoding/Compressing a large integer into alphanumeric value

Tags: php, encoding

I have a very large integer 12-14 digits long and I want to encrypt/compress this to an alphanumeric value so that the integer can be recovered later from the alphanumeric value. I tried to convert this integer using a 62 base and tried to map those values to `a-zA-Z0-9`, but the value generated from this is 7 characters long. This length is still long enough and I want to convert to about 4-5 characters.

Is there a general way to do this or some method in which this can be done so that recovering the integer would still be possible? I am asking the mathematical aspects here but I would be programming this in PHP and I recently started programming in php.

## Edit:

I was thinking in terms of assigning a masking bit and using this in a fashion to generate less number of Chars. I am aware of the fact that the range is not enough and that is the reason I was focusing on using a mathematical trick or a way of representation. The 62 base was an Idea that I already applied but is not working out.

Comment: Do you really need encryption?  Or just compression?

Comment: encryption doesn't ensure that the value generated will be of less characters than the previous one. But if there is an algorithm which can be helpful, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your only choice is to use a larger alphabet. Not base 62, but 64, or even more, which will include "special characters". You're simply running into the pigeon hole principle: you cannot express more possible values in a string than *alphabet size ^ string length*. If you want shorter strings, you have to increase the alphabet.

Comment: so are you saying that base 64, in my case 62, base the best bet to reduce the number of chars. Can there be no algorithm/mathematical way to convert this? I believe there has to be some mathematical way to do this.

Comment: Encryption != Encoding.  Base 64 (or Base 62) will encode, but not encrypt.  Encryption is used so that an unauthorized person cannot view the data.  It sounds like you want encoding in order to compress. Correct?

Comment: yeah, I might have used to terms as synonyms and am sorry for that

Comment: There are more complicated encodings you could use (see, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_Packed_Decimal which is used for the decimal representations on some mainframes) but I don't know how feasible it would be to implement in PHP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

14 digit decimal numbers can express 100,000,000,000,000 values (10<sup>14</sup>).
5 characters of a 62 character alphabet can express 916,132,832 values (62<sup>5</sup>).

You cannot cram the equivalent number of values of a 14 digit number into a 5 character base 62 string. It's simply not possible to express each possible value uniquely.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle. Even base 64 with 7 characters is not enough (only 4,398,046,511,104 possible values). In fact, if you target a 5 character short string you'd need to compensate by using a base 631 alphabet (631<sup>5</sup> = 100,033,806,792,151).

Even compression doesn't help you. It would mean that two or more numbers would need to compress to the same compressed string (because there aren't enough possible unique compressed values), which logically means it's impossible to uncompress them into two different values.

To illustrate this very simply: Say my alphabet and target "string length" consists of *one bit*. That one bit can be `0` or `1`. It can express 2 unique possible values. Say I have a compression algorithm which compresses anything and everything into this one bit. ... How could I possibly uncompress 100,000,000,000,000 unique values out of that one bit with two possible values? If you'd solve that problem, bandwidth and storage concerns would immediately evaporate and you'd be a billionaire.

Comment: yeah.. billionaire. But instead of receiving 100000000000 dollars you'll get just 1 dollar because this "compressed version" transfers faster over bank accounts :) :) :)

Comment: That's just an interesting application of this information theory breakthrough!

Comment: An alphabet with 64 characters can represent 6 bits per character, an alphabet with 8 - only 3 bits. So 8-char expression can be compressed to 64-char based half the size. I don't see the problem. Why such compression is not possible?

Comment: @Dmitri I thought I explained it... The OP was trying to target a message size which simply cannot hold all possible values. Yes, a message of length 4 in an alphabet of 64 characters is the same as a message of length 8 in an alphabet of 8 characters (64^4 == 8^8). That's a simple base conversion, not compression. But 62^5 is way smaller than 10^14 by any measure. You cannot ***losslessly*** convert or compress 10^14 values into 62^5.

Comment: Yes, base conversion. But it does exactly the trick - compresses long integer string into shorter alphanumeric string. Isn't that what the OP was asking? And why is this not compression?

Comment: @Dmitri Yes, but in order for a different base to be able to express the same values, the length of the string needs to scale proportionally. The OP was asking for an *unproportionally short* target string. It's no problem to base convert, but you have accept the minimum necessary string length of the target base, which the OP was having a problem with.

Comment: Sure, it can't be unproportionally short, but you can enlarge the alphabet for better compression. Adding standard ASCII special characters you easily improve the compression rate. Using integer strings directly is a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: @Dmitri Sure, but for a 5 character string to pack the same information as a 14 character decimal string your alphabet would need to be 631 characters. It's still simply unproportional.

Comment: Ok, I didn't look at the question to achieve precisely those numbers, I understood the OP just wanted to get the best compression possible.

Answer (score 3):

With 95 printable ASCII characters you can switch to base 95 encoding instead of 62:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

That way an integer string of length `X` can be compressed into length `Y` base 95 string, where

```
Y = X * log 10/ log 95 = roughly X / 2
```

which is pretty good compression. So from length 12 you get down to 6. If the purpose of compression is to save the bandwidth by using JSON, then base 92 can be good choice (excluding `",\,/` that become escaped in JSON).

Surely you can get better compression but the price to pay is a larger alphabet. Just replace 95 in the above formula by the number of symbols.

Unless of course, you know the structure of your integers. For instance, if they have plenty of zeroes, you can base your compression on this knowledge to get much better results.

Answer (score 2):

because the pigeon principle you will end up with some values that get compressed and other values that get expanded. It simply impossible to create a compression algorithm that compress every possible input string (i.e. in your case your numbers).

If you force the cardinality of the output set to be smaller than the cardinality of the input set you'll get collisions (i.e. more input strings get "compressed" to the same compressed binary string). A compression algorithm should be reversible, right? :)