# java encrypting numeric values to alphanumeric values

Tags: java, encryption, hash, hash-function

I want to encrypt numeric values.

For example;

The value is numeric.

```
String ="8502352664";
```

I want to encrypt it to alphanumeric+numeric. however I need output with only 5 chars.

```
8502352664>AB123
```

`AB123` is an output example.

Can anyone give me any examples for encryption?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Examples of what?

Comment: That can't be done without collisions! If you want to present a ten digit number in a format like AB123.

Comment: Please think like this. I have a customerId. it is 8502352664. I want to use it via browser link(get parameter). However I dont want nobody see it like this. So I want to crypt it. Also some guys have to use this id as 5char(AB123). is it possible?

Comment: Convert it to HEXADECIMAL. Use `Integer.toHexString(8502352664)`. How ever, it has no garuntee to return it in 5 chars...

Comment: @ambigram_maker that's not what I would call encryption

Comment: Does it have to be 5 chars long?

Comment: @UmNyobe Well, its good enough for a question of such quality.

Comment: Even converting it to use a radix of 36, it will be 7 characters. You'll need to convert it to also consider Uppercase and lowercase characters, also maybe symbols that are insensitive to how you might be passing your values.

Comment: You will need an alphabet with 100 different symbols to be able to achieve what you want, assuming that your ids have 10 symbols. `SymbolsCount = exp(ln(10^x-1)/5)` where `x` is the maximum length of the ids in decimal form.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ The maximum you can get is 96 symbols, I wonder if that's sufficient, you'll need to use extra symbols if not. Otherwise you might need a hash, and as @kai says, there'll be collisions.

Comment: POssible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314445/encoding-compressing-a-large-integer-into-alphanumeric-value

Answer (score 0):

I can think of something like this. 
If you have some String you could convert it to this: `11233378 -> B1A2C3A7A8` 
A for single, B for double, C for tripple.

Or you could Caesar Chiffre to do this, move your String by value n. 
`11233378 -> 22344489`.

Just some ideas ..

Comment: that still does not reduce it to a length of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern cryptographic hash functions will not fit into 5 * 8 bits, so it would require more then 5 characters to present them.

If you are willing to compromise on security though you could use something like Javas hashCode for String and then convert it to characters.

The code would look something like this

```
    public String createHash(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int hashcode = s.hashCode();
    byte[] bytes = BigInteger.valueOf(hashcode).toByteArray();

    return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of symbols that I found on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp and I take the first 100 symbols of it. To convert a string of a length of 10 (base 10) to half of its length, you'll need base 100. looking at the below list, divide your string "8502352664" to |85|02|35|26|64| and replace them with the counterpart on the left.

For example, if I got `203`, it will get me `|02|03|` --> `!"`

```
space   %20  - #01
!   %21      - #02
"   %22      - #03
#   %23      - #04
$   %24       - #05
%   %25      - and so on....
&   %26
'   %27
(   %28
)   %29
*   %2A
+   %2B
,   %2C
-   %2D
.   %2E
/   %2F
0   %30
1   %31
2   %32
3   %33
4   %34
5   %35
6   %36
7   %37
8   %38
9   %39
:   %3A
;   %3B
<   %3C
=   %3D
>   %3E
?   %3F
@   %40
A   %41
B   %42
C   %43
D   %44
E   %45
F   %46
G   %47
H   %48
I   %49
J   %4A
K   %4B
L   %4C
M   %4D
N   %4E
O   %4F
P   %50
Q   %51
R   %52
S   %53
T   %54
U   %55
V   %56
W   %57
X   %58
Y   %59
Z   %5A
[   %5B
\   %5C
]   %5D
^   %5E
_   %5F
`   %60
a   %61
b   %62
c   %63
d   %64
e   %65
f   %66
g   %67
h   %68
i   %69
j   %6A
k   %6B
l   %6C
m   %6D
n   %6E
o   %6F
p   %70
q   %71
r   %72
s   %73
t   %74
u   %75
v   %76
w   %77
x   %78
y   %79
z   %7A
{   %7B
|   %7C
}   %7D
~   %7E
    %7F
`   %80
   %81
‚   %82
ƒ   %83    - #100
```

also pay attention to %7F and %81, they are both empty character, I'm not sure if they are treated the same, but for safety purpose, you can select any symbols you like that's not in this list and replace them.